# handling properties that have different values per user in code-first entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Question entity in my web application. A user can like and bookmark a question. Similar to the way Likes function in Facebook, if a question is liked or bookmarked, the question should have **undo-like** or **undo-bookmark** links instead of **like** and **bookmark** links, when the existing questions are listed.

To achieve this, first I think I will need to define `List<Question> LikedQuestions` property for `User` entity, and `List<User> LikedBy` property for `Question` entity, and define Many-to-Many relationship between User and Question entity.

Then, it will be easy to retrieve the liked questions per user. However, my goal is the retrieve the all questions posted in the system, and include **undo-like** (or undo-bookmark) links if the question is liked by the current user. I guess I can achieve this by using LinQ to check if each question is in the `List<Question> LikedQuestions`. But, this seems to be a poor design and may lead to very low performances.

I also thought about adding properties such as `IsLikedByCurrentUser` `IsBookmarkedByCurrentUser` to Question entity. Is this doable?

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my current model:

```
    public abstract class Like
{
    [Key]
    public int LikeItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime WhenLiked { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WhoLiked")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public Person WhoLiked { get; set; }
}

public class PostLike : Like
{
    [Required]
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}

public class CommentLike : Like
{
    [ForeignKey("Comment")]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}

public class PostBookmark
{
    public int PostBookmarkId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BookmarkedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookmarkedBy")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BookmarkedPostId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookmarkedPostId")]
    public Post BookmarkedPost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime WhenBookmared { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> CommentsAssociated { get; set; }
    public List<PostLike> PostLikes { get; set; }
    public List<PostBookmark> PostBookmarks { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Post PostAssociated { get; set; }

    public List<CommentLike> CommentLikes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the fluent API to define the relationships:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Like>()
                    .HasRequired(l => l.WhoLiked)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Likes)
                    .HasForeignKey(l => l.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CommentLike>()
                    .HasRequired(cl => cl.Comment)
                    .WithMany(cm => cm.CommentLikes)
                    .HasForeignKey(cl => cl.CommentId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostLike>()
                    .HasRequired(pl => pl.Post)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostLikes)
                    .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostBookmark>()
                    .HasRequired(pb => pb.Person)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                    .HasForeignKey(pb => pb.BookmarkedBy);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostBookmark>()
                    .HasRequired(pb => pb.BookmarkedPost)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                    .HasForeignKey(pb => pb.BookmarkedPostId);
```

Comment: Sounds feasible, try it out & refactor as necessary!  If you have a relationships between the two entities then you don't need to get everything, but instead just the linked elements.  Since you're using LINQ-to-Entities it will be converted to SQL (assuming that's your underlying data source) which is very efficient at this type of query.

Comment: @JNYRanger however in this case I will use OnDataBinding event to check if the pos is already in the current user's bookmarked-post list. If so, the link text will be undo-bookmark. Don't you think this is too many db connections?  This will repear for each post binded. Why not retrieve everything at once? However i don't know how to do this.  That's why I asked actually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
//Question Model:
[NotMapped]
public bool IsLikedByCurrentUser {get;set;}
```

The `NotMapped` attribute will keep this field out of the DB but still allow you to use it as part of your model.

Then when doing your binding or selecting:

```
Select(x => new {
   //other properties
    x.IsLikedByCurrentUser = x.LikedBy.Contains(User.Id)
})
```

This is pseudo code obviously, but I believe the `Contains` gets converted to a SQL `in ()` statement. As long as `LikedBy` is a foreign property of a collection of user ids.

If you provide more of your model I'll update my answer.

**Update**

This is how I would do it:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsLikedByCurrentUser {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentsAssociated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostLike> PostLikes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostBookmark> PostBookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResults Index() {
    var posts = _db.Posts.Select(x => new Post {
        Title = x.Title,
        IsLikedByCurrentUser = x.PostLike.Select(y => y.UserId).Contains(User.Id)
    });
    return View();
}
```

I'm still doing this from memory so you might have to make some adjustments.

**Update 2**

Something else you could do that might be a better practice is to create a "`ViewModel`" type of class that has the `IsLikedByCurrentUser` property instead of using a `NotMapped` column. The select statement would then be

```
Select(x => new PostVidewModel {
    Title = x.Title,
    IsLikedByCurrentUser = x.PostLike.Select(y => y.UserId).Contains(User.Id)
});
```

Comment: I provided the related parts of my model, I hope I did not miss any part. Please, let me know if you need for information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: thank you @Eonasdan, I forget to mention, my application is Web Forms application, not MVC. Does this make any difference? And, do you know any resources that directly explains `x=> new Post { }` structure?

Comment: mm I don't think it should. Just exchange my controller example for where you're loading the data. `_db.` is the `dataContext` object, in case that wasn't clear